# The #define NDEBUG doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, assert, stdio, abort

I read in a text that placing the following preprocessor line ignores all the subsequent assert preprocessor directives. But this doesn't seem to work and the assert statement infact is processed by the preprocessor and aborts the program when the condition in the assert in not satisfied(I know the abort is a correct behaviour when the assert condition is not satisfied). My question is why is the assert statement not ignored by placing #define NDEBUG. The code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>
#define NDEBUG

int main(){
    int x = 0;

    assert (x!=0);  

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Change the order of appearance, then it should work:

```
#define NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>
```

`NDEBUG` is used to define the `assert()` macro in `<assert.h>` conditionally.

Answer (score 6):

All previous answers are correct.

But assert are not meant to be used by adding `#define NDEBUG` in the source code.

The canonical way:

1) Use `#include <assert.h>` and call `assert()` in your code.

2) Then at build time:

2a) `gcc blablabla` : this is a **debug** build, NDEBUG is not defined, and assert() goes into action.

2b) `gcc blablabla -DNDEBUG blablabla` : this is a **production** build, NDEBUG is defined, assert() does nothing.

Assertions are a way to spot errors/exceptional conditions at *development time*. The NDEBUG could be spelled as "NOT_DEBUG".

Answer (score 3):

Defines does not work like this. You should define your NDEBUG **before** including assert.h

This happening because inside `assert.h` NDEBUG is checked using `#ifdef`:

```
#ifdef  NDEBUG
# define assert(expr)           (__ASSERT_VOID_CAST (0))
#else
//....
```

Answer (score 1):

`NDEBUG` has to appear before the header is included. This is exactly specified in the standard.

> The header  defines the `assert` and `static_assert` macros and
>   refers to another macro,
>
> ```
>      NDEBUG
> ```
>
> which is not defined by `<assert.h>` **If
>   NDEBUG is defined as a macro name at the point in the source file
>   where `<assert.h>` is included, the assert macro is defined simply as**
>
> ```
>      #define assert(ignore) ((void)0)**
> ```
>
> The assert macro is redefined according to the current state of NDEBUG each time that  is
>   included.

from N1570, emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, add definition in CMakeLists.txt sounds not bad.

```
set(release 1)

if (release)
    add_definitions(-DNDEBUG)
endif ()
```

just `set(release 0)` if you debug, and `set(release 1)` when release

It's more convenient and human-readable.

Comment: CMake should already be doing this for you. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302265/does-cmake-build-type-release-imply-dndebug