# Does CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release imply -DNDEBUG?

Tags: c, cmake, assert

Does [`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) implicitly imply [`-DNDEBUG`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/)?

**If not:** isn't it reasonable to expect that this implication takes place?

I want to know if following [CMake](https://cmake.org/) code is redundant in my *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
if (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
    add_definitions(-DNDEBUG)
endif()
```

Comment: I checked it out and it turns out that *CMake* append `-DNDEBUG` flag, but it's still problematic because [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) does **not** explicitly mention if `-DNDEBUG` flag is added when `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` option is present. I prefer to avoid writing code based on undocumented behaviour because it may change in future CMake versions (though potential consequences would be small).

Comment: @iharob: Author wants to know, whether this behaviour is standard/common, and is observed on **all machines**. That's why checking that on his *current machine* is not sufficient (and author *did that*). Googling is not showing answer at least on the first page. And answer is actually not so simple as it seems to be. Intention to remove redudant code, given in the question, is perfectly OK for programming. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I see, I am deeply sorry. The utility with *undocumented* documentation is *qmake* and I didn't remember that, I will delete the comment as it's misleading.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, it is set by CMake. Grepping through the CMake code reveals, that for a host of compilers it is set. Probably they set it only for these compilers, which accepts this flag. Here one of the lines concerning GCC:

```
Modules/Compiler/GNU.cmake:  set(CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT "-O3 -DNDEBUG")
```

But be aware that many projects overwrite release/debug flags without preserving the initial setting and also overwriting user's definitions.

Comment: Starting in 3.7 you can set `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT` explicitly and control all the compile flags - see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_INIT.html.