# Google Benchmark: "Library built in Debug mode"

Tags: cmake, microbenchmark

I have the googlebenchmark source code in `~/usr/local` and build
the whole thing with `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` from inside `build`:
`cd build; cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release; make`,
and then in my project's `CMakeLists.txt` I have the following:

```
set(BENCHMARK_ROOT ~/local/benchmark/build/src)
set(BENCHMARK_INCLUDE_DIR ~/local/benchmark/include)
```

I would like to keep the library in my home directory, as is shown here,
and it works fine with this set-up; my `C++` project can see `benchmark`.
However, the warning `***WARNING*** Library was built as DEBUG. Timings may be affected.`
is still there, so I believe the `README.md` does not tell the whole story.
How to fix this? I even tried with 
`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBENCHMARK_DOWNLOAD_DEPENDENCIES=ON ../`
so that it actually downloads `googletest` and stores it in `third_party` directory inside `build`. However, issuing `make` leads it to an error: it cannot find the `googletest` it has just built.

EDIT: I've included

```
if (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
    add_definitions(-DNDEBUG)
endif()
```

into the `CMakeLists.txt` of `benchmark`, still the warning persists.
The approach has been suggested [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302265/does-cmake-build-type-release-imply-dndebug](http://in%20this%20SE%20thread.)

Comment: The error message is about absence of `NDEBUG` macro definition when compile the project (see e.g. [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/benchmark-discuss/i_xsvxdcgS4)). Check that the macro is defined in your case. (You may use `make VERBOSE=1` for check actual command lines which build your project). CMake defines the macro in `Release` builds *by default*, but it depends from your `CMakeLists.txt` whether this default is applied.

Answer (score 0):

After including

```
if (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
    add_definitions(-DNDEBUG)
endif()
```

into `benchmark`'s `CMakeLists.txt` and re-building it, and linking
my executable towards newly built library, voila,
here is a sample output:

> ...  {
>       "type": "Unified",
>       "level": 3,
>       "size": 25344000,
>       "num_sharing": 16   } ], "load_avg": [0.4,0.18,0.23], "library_build_type": "release"

Thus, sometimes it makes sense to install the library from sources, in order to build it as `Release`.

In addition, one does something like

```
set(BENCHMARK_ROOT ~/local/benchmark/build/src)
target_link_directories(my_executable PUBLIC ${BENCHMARK_ROOT})
```

after having built the library inside (in my case) `~/local/nechmark/build/`