# Google Benchmark: "***WARNING*** Library was built as DEBUG. Timings may be affected."

Tags: build, bazel, bazel-rules, google-benchmark

In `~/install/benchmark`, I have checked out Google Benchmark (https://github.com/google/benchmark) and built it in Release mode according to the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59274864/google-benchmark-library-built-in-debug-mode).

In `~/personal-projects/benchmarking`, I have my own code with a `BUILD` file and a `WORKSPACE` file. In the `WORKSPACE` file, I've got

```
local_repository(
    name = "com_google_benchmark",
    path = "../../install/benchmark",
)
```

And in the `BUILD` file, I have

```
cc_binary(
    name = "fast_inverse_sqr_root",
    srcs = ["fast_inverse_sqr_root.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "@com_google_benchmark//:benchmark_main",
    ],
)
```

When I `bazel run //fast_inverse_sqr_root`, it says: `***WARNING*** Library was built as DEBUG. Timings may be affected.`

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59274864/google-benchmark-library-built-in-debug-mode) related question but that person is using cmake while I'm using Bazel to build my code. I'm not sure what is going on here. Why is it saying the library was built as DEBUG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try telling Bazel to compile everything in optimized mode: `bazel run -c opt //fast_inverse_sqr_root`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Still pretty confused how this happened, if my `WORKSPACE` is referring to a library that was built with Release mode already. It's not like this `bazel run` invocation is re-building that library. Oh well

Comment: Bazel builds gtest itself. Building it yourself with cmake is not necessary nor relevant to the compiler flags Bazel uses to compile it.

Comment: This is Google Benchmark not gtest, unless I'm misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the benchmark library.